# What does this construct in Pyramid mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

Construction from [pyramid docs](https://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blog_models_and_views.html)

```
@classmethod
def all(cls, request):
    query = request.dbsession.query(BlogRecord)
    return query.order_by(sa.desc(BlogRecord.created))
```

I don't understand what's going on in this statement.

```
query = request.dbsession.query(BlogRecord)
```

As I understand we create an example of a query class, but what do we get from:

1. `query(BlogRecord)` inheritance from BlogRecord?
2. `request.dbsession.query` I have no idea.

Comment: Regarding "where does the BlogRecord come from": it is defined a couple of lessons earlier in the same tutorial: https://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_models.html. The library which maps your Python classes to database tables and allows to query the database is SQLAlchemy (Pyramid itself has no built-in persistence mechanism), you need to have a look the SQLAlchemy docs to see how models and querying works: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you walked through all the previous steps in the tutorial including [1. Create your pyramid_blogr project structure](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-blogr/en/latest/project_structure.html#create-your-pyramid-blogr-project-structure) and [Adding model definitions](https://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_models.html#adding-model-definitions), you would know that `BlogRecord` is an object or an instance of the class `BlogRecord` which inherits from the SQLAlchemy metadata `Base` class defined in `models.meta` which was created using the `alchemy` cookiecutter. This line:

```
query = request.dbsession.query(BlogRecord)
```

creates a variable `query` and assigns a database query object as its value.  It does not execute the query yet. The next line does that, and returns the result.

Going further, taking apart `request.dbsession.query`, the `request` portion is a [request](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html) object that is passed around in Pyramid.  Attributes can be attached to the request object, in this case the `dbsession` object (an SQLAlchemy database session object) is the attribute.  This in turn has a method named `query` which accepts a data model as its argument.

This is mostly Python stuff regarding classes and methods, and not specific to Pyramid. I'd suggest reading more about those in the Python documentation and tutorials.

Note: the answer from @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 is completely wrong. Pyramid does not use the `requests` (plural) library. Pyramid has a [`request` (singular) object](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html). Also the "docs" are a community-contributed tutorial, not documentation.  For official documentation and tutorials, visit https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html